# python unittest - nochsuchelementexception on element that had already been found within the same test

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

Element won't be found after after it has been clicked on within the same test. `NoSuchElementException` is raised.

I've tried `time.sleep()`, `implicitly_wait`, `explicit_wait` ...

```
def test_sort_name_asc(self):
    street = self.driver.find_element_by_id('street')
    street.send_keys('Mainstreet', Keys.ENTER)

    name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='table']/thead/tr/th[2]")
    name.click()
```

...

```
    name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='table']/thead/tr/th[2]/a")
    self.assertEqual(name.get_attribute('class'), 'table__order is-active asc')
```

As soon as I comment out the second `name` it works perfectly fine. Else it raises an `NoSuchElementException`. This happens even when I reduce the second name's path to exactly to the first one's. (Though the tag definitely exists!)

Comment: After clicking the element the first time, the xpath changed and it is no longer available on the DOM, or it is stale.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that element no longer exists after clicking on it. As per below statement

```
name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='table']/thead/tr/th[2]")
name.click()
```

When you click on element name it maybe gets updated or disappears so for the second time when you try to find the element it shows error `NoSuchElementException`.
To get more details about this error you can follow this link
https://selenium-by-arun.blogspot.com/2017/05/nosuchelementexception-webdriver.html

Or assemble your code in below manner if it is applicable

```
def test_sort_name_asc(self):
    street = self.driver.find_element_by_id('street')
    street.send_keys('Mainstreet', Keys.ENTER)

    name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='table']/thead/tr/th[2]")
    self.assertEqual(name.get_attribute('class'), 'table__order is-active asc')
    name.click()
```

Hope it would help.

Comment: unfortunately I can't assamble code in the suggested way. (Things need to happen in between). The element gets indeed updated when clicking on it. Nonetheless its still there afterwards. Thus I assumed it should still able to be found. I read the link but I still don't get it. Somehow it must be possible to find an element even after it has been updated. - cheers for your help! Appreciate!

Comment: Hmmm... There could be one more reason for your error `NoSuchElementException` that I have explained in my answer 2. try that maybe it could work.

Answer (score 0):

If the tag is definitely present then the reason for the error `NoSuchElementException` could be delay issue for an example after clicking on an element for the first time maybe it requires some time to load the element completely but in your script, you are immediately fetching the element right after clicking.

If this would be the issue then it would be solved by using of delays called as `webdriverwait`

Try with below code but you have to import two modules which I have mention in code

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


def test_sort_name_asc(self):
    delay = 30
    street = self.driver.find_element_by_id('street')
    street.send_keys('Mainstreet', Keys.ENTER)

    name = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table']/thead/tr/th[2]")))
    name.click()

    name = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table']/thead/tr/th[2]/a")))
    self.assertEqual(name.get_attribute('class'), 'table__order is-active asc')
```